# how to transfer excel type file into html type file?

Tags: r, excel

I have some excel type files and want to transfer them into html files.

And I hope I can open them in broswer and as a hyperlink in shiny using href="***.html".

But if I just save the excel file as html ，it doesn't work well .All the contents will not show align center.

Just like this:
[image]

But I hope it will show perfectly like this:
[image]

Now I only have one method that is opening the excel in broswer and saved as html type.

Who can help me and give me some other methods.

Vary thankful !

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  You've added tags for both Shiny and r to your question but mention neither in the text.  Why are they relevant?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I just want to know how to transfer excel into html perfectly. 

And I have finished the part work related to shiny .This is just a quote. I have edited it just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an Excel file to HTML with the following code in R :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_Excel_File <- "D:/excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File, ReadOnly = TRUE)

# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff198017(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN for the file formats
xlWbk$SaveAs(filename = "D:\\excel_File.html", FileFormat = 44)
```

Comment: Thank you. It has been finished two years ago.